# Create CSS Semi-Circles

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a filled circle that contains a number like so:

[image]

How would I go about splitting this into two semi-circles, so that I can store two different numbers within it, like so:

[image]

My CSS is as follows:

```
.oval {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000000;
    color: white;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: medium;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `border-radius`

```css
.left-half,
.right-half {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 1px;
  background: black;
}
.left-half:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 80px 0 0 80px;
}
.right-half:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 0 80px 80px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="left-half">21</div>
  <div class="right-half">12</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use  **SVG**

```css
.text {
  font-size: 16px;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg width="105.5px" height="97.874px" viewBox="0 0 105.5 97.874">
  <path d="M50.423,0.609v96.76c-26.72,0-48.38-21.66-48.38-48.38C2.043,22.269,23.703,0.609,50.423,0.609z" />
  <path d="M103.526,49.494c0,26.72-21.66,48.38-48.38,48.38V1.114C81.866,1.114,103.526,22.774,103.526,49.494z" />
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 20.0771 52.5107)" class="text">21</text>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 73.1807 53.0166)" class="text">12</text>
</svg>
```

---

**Update**: You could also just create circle with two spans inside and add one line in middle with **pseudo-class**

```css
.circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle:before {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>12</span><span>24</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it changes the size of the circle, therefore it doesn't match with my other circles that are full circles (not semi-circle)

Comment: The size still seems larger than the original ones. Also, how would I apply this to my class half-oval instead of all divs

Comment: Size is just for demo you should adjust that to your needs, how about this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/654/

Comment: @Eitan K i adjusted the sizes

Comment: Would I use it like so, so that it's specific to the half-oval css class?: .half-oval instead of div and .half-oval div:nth-child(1)? Doing this I only see half the circle, but the size looks correct

Comment: Can you create fiddle, i am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 7):

You only need to add a line in the middle (either using a pseudo-element or using a gradient like in the below snippet) and then place the content inside it using two `span` elements.

```css
.oval {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000000;
  color: white;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: medium;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), white calc(50% - 1px), white calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px));
}
span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='oval'>
  <span>21</span>
  <span>12</span>
</div>
```

---

Or you can do it like in the below snippet where the semi-circles are created using a pseudo-element.

```css
.oval {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 37.5px;
  height: 75px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.oval:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  z-index: -1;
}
.oval:nth-of-type(1):before {
  left: 0px;
}
.oval:nth-of-type(2):before {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='oval'>
  21
</div>
<div class='oval'>
  12
</div>
```

---

Or you can even use `radial-gradient` background. This is just another method (*for fun*) and I don't really recommend this option.

```css
.oval {
  float: left;
  width: 37.5px;
  height: 75px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: medium;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center right, black 97.5%, transparent 100%);
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center left, black 97.5%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='oval'>21</div>
<div class='oval'>12</div>
```

Comment: The line seems to be crooked

Comment: In which snippet @EitanK (also tell me the browser). It can't be crooked because in the first snippet it is a linear-gradient line and in the second and third, it is just a margin which is always straight line.

Comment: The first snippet using chrome

Comment: Very weird @EitanK. I am also using Chrome only. Have you changed the size (or) gradient (or) anything else within the code? If you've changed, can you create a fiddle with the changed code so that I can see if the crooked line appears for me?

Comment: I may be using it wrong, I am very bad at front-end. I changed your span to span.half-oval, since I do not want it to apply to all spans (I am using .half-oval instead of oval) and am calling it like so.     <div class="col-xs-2">
        <h4>Families</h4>
        <div class="half-oval">
            <span class="half-oval">21</span>
            <span class="half-oval">12</span>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: @EitanK: Changing the class is fine but don't assign the same class to the `div` and `span`. Instead assign the half-oval class to the `div` like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hphsvm10/). But this shouldn't be the reason for a crooked line and I don't see one in the fiddle linked in this comment also :(

Comment: It looks like that for my in the fiddle as well :-/

Comment: I am out of ideas @EitanK. This is what I see in Chrome (v51.0.2704.19 dev-m) - http://i.stack.imgur.com/9XaKp.png

Comment: I appreciate your help. This is what I see in Chrome (49.0.2623.112) http://i.stack.imgur.com/LuQRs.jpg

Answer (score 3):

## SVG solution

This seems like a graphical problem.
So i would suggest to use SVG instead of CSS to create such a shape.

```css
svg {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M47, 5
           A 45 45, 0, 0, 0, 47 95" fill="Orange"/>
  <path d="M52, 5
           A 45 45, 0, 1, 1, 52 95" fill="Orange"/>
  <text x="12" y="60" fill="black" font-size="25px">25</text>
  <text x="57" y="60" fill="black" font-size="25px">16</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.l {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  background: #000000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 103%;
}
.r {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  background: #000000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:80px;
  font-size: 103%;
}
```

```html
<div class='l'>x1</div>
<div class='r'>x2</div>
```